# Rails bundle "Can't find GEM in any of the sources" in Docker Container only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems

I'm using Rails in a Docker container, and every once in a while I run into this issue that I have no idea how to solve. When adding a new gem to the Gemfile, upon rebuilding the Docker Image + Container, the build will fail with the common bundler error `Could not find [GEM_NAME] in any of the sources; Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems`. This *only* occurs to me when I try to build the image in Docker, if I run a regular `bundle install` on my local machine, the Gemfile gets installed correctly and everything works as expected.

I have a fairly standard Dockerfile & `docker-compose` file.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.3

ARG PG_MAJOR
ARG BUNDLER_VERSION
ARG UID
ARG MODE

# Add POSTGRESQL to the source list using the right version
RUN curl -sSL https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | apt-key add - \
  && echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ stretch-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

ENV RAILS_ENV $MODE

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$PG_MAJOR vim
RUN apt-get -y install sudo

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile /usr/src/app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /usr/src/app/Gemfile.lock
ENV BUNDLER_VERSION $BUNDLER_VERSION
RUN gem install bundler:$BUNDLER_VERSION

RUN bundle install

COPY . /usr/src/app

# Add a script to be executed every time the container starts.

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the main process.
CMD ["rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        UID: ${UID:-1001}
        BUNDLER_VERSION: 2.0.2
        PG_MAJOR: 10
        mode: development
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./[REDACTED]:/usr/src/app
      - gem_data_api:/usr/local/bundle:cached
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    user: root
```

I've tried `docker system prune -a`, `docker builder prune -a`, reinstalling Docker, multiple rebuilds in a row, restarting my machine and so on, to no avail. The weird part is that it doesn't happen with every new Gem that I decide to add, only for some specific gems. For example I got this issue once again when trying to add `gem 'sendgrid-ruby'` to my Gemfile. [This](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-ruby#quick-start) is the repo for the gem for reference, and the specific error I get with `sendgrid-ruby` is `Could not find ruby_http_client-3.5.1 in any of the sources`. I tried specifying `ruby_http_client` in my Gemfile, and I also tried `ssh`ing into the Docker container and running `gem install ruby_http_client`, but I get the same errors.

What might be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mounting a named volume over the container's `/usr/local/bundle` directory.  The named volume will get populated from the image, but only the very first time you run the container.  After that the old contents of the named volume will take precedence over the content of the image: using a volume this way will cause Docker to completely ignore any changes you make in the `Gemfile`.

You should be able to delete that `volumes:` line from the `docker-compose.yml` file.  I'm not clear what benefit you would get from keeping the installed gems in a named volume.